# Sequelize remove hook?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm adding a hook to my model at runtime:

```
model.addHook('afterUpdate', 'myHook', function(instance, cb) {
    // Do some stuff
})
```

If some condition is met, I'd like to remove this hook so it no longer fires. Looking at the docs I can only see methods for adding / checking the existence of hooks, not removing them.

Is it possible? Or will I need to come up with my own solution on top (I can think of several ways to do it but wanted to check if Sequelize supports this directly)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this functionality is not there. So, you need to write your solution and remove it manually from `model.options.hooks['afterUpdate']`

Answer (score 1):

After submitting feature request, looks like it's been added:

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/hooks/#removehookhooktype-name

Huzzah for open source!

Comment: wow, cool. so they have added it. 2 weeks after you asked the question ;)